# Joining multiple tables and display all names linked from id

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, join

I have reconstructed my database using the normal form I learned, but now I have problem joining them back into one with all the tables.

I have a song database, the connection of tables are linked like this:

```
songs          artists            song_vocals         song_composers
--------------------------------------------------------------------
song_id        artist_id          song_id             song_id
title          artist_name        artist_id           artist_id
```

There are multiple tables with their foreign key pointing to the artist table.

And I want to display all the information with name like this, I don't want display them by id:

```
song_id        title         vocal          composer
--------------------------------------------------------
1              ABC           John           Cat
```

So far the best I can do is left joining 3 tables, which only gives me *song_id*, *title* and *vocal*:

```
SELECT songs.song_id, songs.title, artists.artist_name as vocal FROM songs
LEFT JOIN song_vocals ON
song_vocals.song_id = songs.song_id
left join artists ON
song_vocals.artist_id = artists.artist_id
```

How can I join more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
songs.title as SongTitle,
a1.artist_name as Vocal,
a2.artist_name as Composer
FROM songs
left join song_vocals ON song_vocals.song_id = songs.song_id
left join artists a1 ON song_vocals.artist_id = a1.artist_id
left join song_composers on songs.song_id = song_composers.song_id
left join artists a2  on a2.artist_id = song_composers.artist_id
```

This is the code block you should use.
If you have two or more links to a table you can use that table more than once if you use ALIAS.
In your ex. "a1","a2" are your ALIAS

Comment: Thanks it works. I have another problem, for example, for songs that were sung by multiple artists, the selection now will display them in multiple rows, how can join them into one single row?

Comment: for that you need to use dynamic sql so you can add names one after other , to give a small example you will have to write a query like @vocal = @vocal+' '+@vocal2

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table for composers if you haven't done so and add the foreign key in your song_vocals table which from your statement is your main table anyway. Then you can add another left join to the composer table after artists though don't forget to put the composers.composer_name (I assume) in your select statement as well.

Comment: The song_composers table was already created and it's referencing to the artists table for the names. If I was to create another composer table just to store the name, then that would be a redundancy problem with names, as I have already have them stored in the artists table.

Comment: You can still LEFT JOIN the composer table with the artist table but give a different alias to the name in the select statement so you don't get confused.

You can also normalize the artist table further by creating a names table and just storing the name id in both artist and composer table so that you end up having 2 junction tables referencing the name table but that might be more counter productive since we don't know the  whole picture of your situation and database schema.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between the tables song_vocals and song_composer

Comment: song_vocals stores the singers of the songs and song_composer stores the composer of the songs. There can be multiple singers singing the same song or multiple composers written a song.